# How to add items to a list in Java

Tags: java

If I had a program that had a list of a few links, how could I add another link to the program, without changing the source code itself? I was going to create a "new" button in the corner of the application, that created a new item (I already know how to do this part)

Comment: if it is a list then simply listname.add will suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the comment said, if it is a list then you could make it so that when you press the button it calls `listname.add("...")` and adds it to the list. Just for future reference, when asking questions, try to put as much detail as you can in the question, to help people answer it.